# Are there any known health risks with taking megadoses of beta carotene?

Tags: micronutrients

According to the research I've done, taking high amounts of vitamin A in animal form can lead to issues (Vitamin A1, retinol). However, the Carotenoid form (ex: beta carotene) seems harmless.

I heard some people can take megadoses of vitamin A regularly, and the only real side-effect is Carotenaemia, which is harmless (and sometimes desired - for fair-skinned people, it acts as a natural tan).

Is there any excessive harm to the liver for chronic use of - say 10,000 IU of beta carotene? How about 100,000 IU of beta carotene?

Comment: I edited the title to reflect the actual question. Megadoses of vitamin A are definitely harmful, but that's not what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing on [my previous answer about Vitamin A risks](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/913/taking-supplements-space-out-my-vitamin-a-and-the-others/915#915), the only known risk of large doses of carotenoids is [an increased risk of lung cancer if you smoke or work with asbestos](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminA-HealthProfessional/#h8).